# With rethinkdb, how to use the "use" database command in the data explorer dashboard

Tags: rethinkdb

How can I set the default database to something other than 'test' in the RethinkDb data explorer dashboard?

I tried using the command `conn.use('mydb')` but is says conn is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a default database in the data explorer is currently not implemented, but you can check or bump [this for progress on the issue](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/829).

You have to give it explicitly:

```
r.db('mydb').table('mytable') ...
```